# How to compare Sheet Names with Array elements and execute tasks on Google Sheets using script?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

The goal is to get each sheet name and check if it's not in the array. If not, then certain ranges are copied into a "database" sheet and then compare the next sheet and so on.

The problem is that itis comparing, it is giving me `-1` as the result and it is executing the tasks, when it shouldn't be and I can't see where the flaw is.

Here's the code:

```
function concatenarResumos() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var databaseSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Database");
  var processedSheetsRng = ss.getSheetByName("Suporte").getRange("F6:F").getValues().flat();
  var shts = ss.getSheets();

  for (var j = 0; j < shts.length; j++) {
    for (var n = 0; n < processedSheetsRng.length; n++) {
      if (processedSheetsRng[n].indexOf(shts[j].getSheetName() === -1)) {

        shts[j].activate;
        var sheetName = shts[j].getSheetName();
        Logger.log("Sheet Name: " + sheetName);
        Logger.log("Processed Sheet Name: " + processedSheetsRng[n])

        var data = shts[j].getRange("C4").getValue();
        var naoConforme = shts[j].getRange("B8:G12").getValues();
        shts[j].getRange("B8:G12").copyTo(databaseSheet.getRange(databaseSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 2, 6, naoConforme.length), { contentsOnly: true });

        var targetCol = databaseSheet.getRange('A:A').getValues();
        var maxIndex = targetCol.reduce(function (maxIndex, row, index) {
          return row[0] === "" ? maxIndex : index;
        }, 0);
        databaseSheet.getRange(maxIndex + 2, 1, naoConforme.length, 1).setValue(data);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the logger output:
[image]

Comment: `Logger.log("Encontrado? " + shts[j].getSheetName().indexOf(processedSheetsRng[n] == -1))` What are you trying to do here?

Comment: @TheMaster to check the output of the indexOf... I seem to have gotten lost here...

Comment: Search mdn for indexOf if you don't know how to use it. `.getSheetName()` returns a ``String``. The syntax is `a1D_array.indexOf(a_string)`

Comment: Fixed it! Thanks, @TheMaster

Comment: Read [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays) and practice it in a separate project. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for free resources and more details.

Comment: Hi @AntonioSantos, I highly suggest that you post your solution as an answer so that other users with similar issues will be able to refer to your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function concatenarResumos() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const dsh = ss.getSheetByName("Database");
  const ssh = ss.getSheetByName("Suporte");
  const svs = ssh.getRange(6, 6, sh.getLastRow() - 5).getValues().flat();
  const shts = ss.getSheets();

  for (let j = 0; j < shts.length; j++) {
    for (let n = 0; n < svs.length; n++) {
      if (~svs[n].indexOf(shts[j].getName())) {
        let d1 = shts[j].getRange("C4").getValue();
        shts[j].getRange("B8:G12").copyTo(dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1, 2, 6, d2.length), { contentsOnly: true });
        let tcol = dsh.getRange(1, 1, dsh.getLastRow()).getValues();
        let maxIndex = tcol.reduce(function (maxIndex, row, index) {return row[0] === "" ? maxIndex : index;}, 0);
        dsh.getRange(maxIndex + 2, 1, d2.length, 1).setValue(d1);
      }
    }
  }
```

Ranges like `F6:F` & `A:A` are bad to use with google apps script because they create a lot of nulls at the end of the array which need to get filtered out.